# Kubuntu - kcm_printer_manager - Windows printer via SAMBA - Browse button greyed out

Tags: kubuntu, printing, samba, sharing, smb

In `/usr/bin/kcmshell5 kcm_printer_manager`, when I click on "Add printer" and then on "Window printer via SAMBA", the "Browse" button is greyed out.

Instead, by running `system-config-printer` (the GNOME equivalent), after clicking on Add->Printer, then on "Network printer" and then on "Window Printer via SAMBA", the "Browse" button works and it is clickable (after installing the `python-smbc` package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered it is greyed out because it is a [feature not implemented yet](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=400613)